# How to make the time.sleep an input using PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, time, sleep, python-3.8, pysimplegui

How can I make an input option where the value inputted is used to sleep and not the time in the code 'time.sleep(10)', for example I inputted 30 into the Psg.Input after i press on punch i want it to wait 30 seconds then break

```
import PySimpleGUI as Psg
import time
import pause
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
loop = 0
cancel_loop = 0
punch_wait = 0
punch_time = 0
keyboard = Controller()
layout = [[Psg.Button("punch")],
          [Psg.Button("Close")]]
window = Psg.Window("App", size=(300, 270)).Layout(layout)
def cancel():
    if event == "Close":
        pass
def d_press():
    keyboard.press(Key.right)
    pause.milliseconds(punch_time)
    keyboard.release(Key.right)
    pause.milliseconds(punch_wait)
    keyboard.release(Key.space)
    return event
def space_press():
    keyboard.press(Key.space)
    pause.milliseconds(1)
def movement():
    d_press()
    space_press()
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == Psg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Close":
        break
    if event == "punch":
        punch_wait = 300
        punch_time = 85
        loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        movement()
        cancel()
        time.sleep(10)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `time.sleep` will block your code in the main thread and there maybe no response for your GUI.

Prefer to do it in other thread. Following code show the way to go.

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def action(window, punch_time, wait_time):
    print("Key Pressed - Space")
    print("Key Pressed - Right")
    print(f"Wait {punch_time} seconds")
    sleep(punch_time)
    print("Key Released - Right")
    print(f"Wait {wait_time} seconds")
    sleep(wait_time)
    print("Key Released - Space")
    print("Thread finished\n")
    # Call window.write("EVENT", "VALUE") in thread to update GUI if required

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Punch time", size=10), sg.Input("", size=10, key='Punch Time')],
    [sg.Text("Wait time",  size=10), sg.Input("", size=10, key='Wait Time')],
    [sg.Button('Punch'), sg.Button('Exit')],
]

window = sg.Window('App', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Punch':
        try:
            punch_time, wait_time = float(values['Punch Time']), float(values['Wait Time'])
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong value for time')
            continue
        threading.Thread(target=action, args=(window, punch_time, wait_time), daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'EVENT':
        value = values[event]
        """ Update GUI here """

window.close()
```